# Как получить в 1 массив все значения из многомерного массива?

Tags: php, symfony

Всем привет, тренеруюсь сейчас на Symfony и не могу разобраться как мне запихнуть все значения из многомерного массива по datе в 1 массив.. до этого данная функция была на Laravel там метод pluck применял все ок было..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так сейчас до первого значения добираюсь

```html
$apiDate['items'][0]['start']['date']
```

Comment: $res=count($apiDate['items']); for ($i=0; $i < $res; $i++) { 
$new[]=$apiDate['items'][$i]['start']['date'];
} print_r($new);

Comment: да все супер спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $res=count($apiDate['items']); 
    for ($i=0; $i < $res; $i++) 
    {
 $new[]=$apiDate['items'][$i]['start']['date']; 
    } 
    print_r($new);
```